# Why developers use ::before pseudo element with display:table on parent divs

Tags: html, css, html-table, pseudo-element, display

I saw that on most websites people often use on parent `<div>`s `::before` pseudo with `content:'';` *(i know that you need to put the content)* and `display: table` and I can't figure out why.

[image: image1]

and

[image: image2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "clearfix" you can know more by simply google-ing<sup>1</sup>. There are many versions of it. The one in the screenshots is probably Nicolas Gallagher's version, you can read more about it [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

<sup>1</sup> [This](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html) provides a simple intro imo

Answer (score 1):

"clearfix" is kind of a hack to fix zero height of parent elements when all of it's children elements are floated. This way, the parent can keep it's height.